# I have not touched this matter a long time

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

> I have an exam in my university on biology, and I **didn't touch** this matter a long time.

What is the right way to say it in present perfect?

Is it correct to say:

> I **have not touched** this matter a long time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In American English, I would use "material" or even "subject" rather than "matter." Thus,

> I have an exam in my university on Biology, and I haven't touched this
>   material in a long time.

An alternative to "touched" would be "studied."

> I have an exam in my university on Biology, and I haven't studied this
>   material in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be correct:

> - I have an exam in my university on biology, and I haven't touched this matter in a long time.
> - I have not touched this matter in a long time.